# Why bootstrap 3 is not loading in django

Tags: django

Why bootstap is not loading

I have provided the template code.

```
{% extends "posts/base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block content %}
<h4>Create New Post</h4>
<form method="POST" id="postForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is showing like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puY8j.png)

why bootstrap is not loading. How can I do it?

Comment: could you show your base.html file? Have you provided link to bootstrap 3 css and js file there? Are the paths give correct everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

add these line

```
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}
```